# Is there a way I can center the vertical and horizontal scrollbars in a ScrollPane in javafx 8?

Tags: javafx-8, centering, scrollpane, scrollbars

Is there a way I can center the vertical and horizontal scrollbars in a ScrollPane in javafx 8 (by programming/using scenebuilder) so that it is centered from the moment I execute the program?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    scrollPane.setHvalue((scrollPane.getHmax() - scrollPane.getHmin())/2);
    scrollPane.setVvalue((scrollPane.getVmax() - scrollPane.getVmin())/2);
```